# mp4 in IIS 7 not playing good

Tags: iis-7, mp4

I embed a MP4 movie in a page. The problem is that the video doesn't play good. There are snowy effect when you play the video.

The embeded MP4 is playing good in IIS 6 but not in IIS 7.

The MIME is set to .mp4/video/mp4

Server: IIS 7
OS:     Windows 32 bit

What settings are needed to stream it smoothly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling and a lot of reading and no solutions were found. We decided to use wowza server and now .m4v and .mp4 video files are playing.